# Convert integration to polar and solve

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

> Evaluate the iterated integral $$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{3+2y-y^2}}\cos\left(x^2+(y-1)^2\right)\,dy\,dx$$

Confused on how $y=0$ and $y=\sqrt{3+2y-y^2}$. Is this a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: Use $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=1+r\sin(\theta)$

Comment: It looks to me that they switched the $dy$ and $dx$ when they typed the question.

Comment: ok so it should be x = 0,  x = sqrt(3+2y−y^2) ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you confused about? As far as I can see the limits for the integral wrt $y,$ being $0$ and $\frac {1+\sqrt 7}{2}$ from the given conditions, are consistent with everything else.

Comment: Im a bit lost on how to find the  theta and r.
i cant seem to solve the equation by substituting in $rcostheta$ and $ rsintheta$
in $x^2=3+2y-y^2$